# JQuery with css3 keydown keyCode = 37 and 39

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tested both ways. jquery animation and css3 transition, and css3 is a little bit faster. But i have a problem with the following code:

```
 $(document).keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
    var DocHeight = $(document).height();
    $('.container').css("margin-top","-="+DocHeight)
}
});
```

if i hit twice on keyCode 39 (arrow to the right) than my transition is **outer space**. Does anyone has an solution for this thing?

**outer space**

maybe not the correct word. But the problem is. if i hit twice the arrow key i'll get the last request, in other words... animation is started, and another animation start from the position that i don't want.

example: hit #1 margin-top is at 0px and goes to 1024px. but when i hit it twice the margin-top is at 23px, and it stops at 1047px.

This is not what i want. It has to stop at 1024px.

I hope so.

Comment: But what is it that you want it to do?

Comment: What do you mean its `outer space`? Whats it doing?

Comment: prevent double animations, if i hit twice the animations starts from another point, that i didn't calculate

Comment: Looks like you are subtracting the entire document height every time you hit the button.

Comment: Every time you click the right arrow it is still subtracting margin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var mTop = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
    var DocHeight = $(document).height();
    mTop = mTop - parseInt(DocHeight);
    $('.container').css("margin-top", mTop);
  }
});
```

This just keeps on going, if you just want it to animate once and stop, try something like:

```
var mTop = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
    var WinHeight = $(window).height();
    mTop = parseInt(WinHeight);
    $('.container').css("margin-top", -mTop);
  }
});
```

Using document height is a bad idea when moving stuff with margins, also just adding the document height to the css each time with "-=" will cause problems when you hit the button before the animation is finished and it adds to a value that is somewhere inbetween, you should do the math in a variabe instead, and use that variable for setting the css for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

    var DocHeight = $(document).height();
    if (DocHeight > 1024) {
        $('.container').css("margin-top", "1024px")
    } else {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            $('.container').css("margin-top", "-=" + DocHeight)
        }
    }

});
```

This code just checks if `DocHeight` is above 1024 or not.

Find an Demo Here: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/fRYwM/
I use `$('.container').css("margin-top", "+=" + DocHeight)` for the example but using it with the `-` will work too.

**Edit:
(I know you don't need it):**

I edited the code so it works twice as good:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    check();
});
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var DocHeight = $(document).height();
    if (DocHeight > 1024) {
        $('.container').css("margin-top", "1024px")
    } else {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            if (DocHeight > 1024) {
                $('.container').css("margin-top", "1024px")
            }
            $('.container').css("margin-top", "+=" + DocHeight)
        }
    }

});
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    var DocHeight = $(document).height();
    if (DocHeight > 1024) {
        $('.container').css("margin-top", "1024px")
    }
});
function check() {
    if (DocHeight > 1024) {
        $('.container').css("margin-top", "1024px")
    }
    check();
}
```

The demo for this is: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/fRYwM/1/

Comment: sorry i don't need that, because i need to get the full height off the document

Comment: Huh, this will. Once you click twice.

Comment: what i mean is, 1024 must be variable. i use in css3 the following:
'-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;'
to get full width and height on every screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery `animate` then you can use `.is(":animated")` to only start a new animation if one isn't already in progress.

```
var $container = $('.container');

if (e.keyCode == 39 && !$container.is(":animated")) { 
    var DocHeight = $(document).height();
    $container.animate(...)
}
```

This will only start the animation if one is not already in progress.

Comment: Hmm i tried that one, but it isn't working http://home.raymondidema.nl/deco/#werk

Comment: Answer updated slightly.  Sort of misunderstood that you were using css transitions.  This applies to jquery `animate`.

Comment: okay i tried both. Problem is still remaining... :( or maybe it is a bug... :)